# Android StackBox.java in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am working on a custom ROM for Android 5.0 and I found out the class StackBox.java in : frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/ doesn't exist anymore.

Does anybody know if there is a new class which replaced it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When and where _did_ that file exist? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: In Andoid 4.4. In the path : frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/

Comment: Okay, but that's not the path you talked about in the question. I updated the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git to find out when and how a file has been removed or renamed.

```
$ cd frameworks/base
$ git log -M --name-status --all -- services/java/com/android/server/wm/StackBox.java
```

For me this yields the following at the top:

```
commit ed6649f89f236ea9e665028bd33d6d804b906a92
Author: Craig Mautner <cmautner@google.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 2 14:08:25 2013 -0800

    DO NOT MERGE: Eliminate StackBox.

    StackBox is too constraining. Adding size and position to TaskStacks
    directly makes stack positioning and management more flexible and
    prepares for ActivityView.

    Change-Id: I33c6b4e1c23a5a8069fd507c160bcb34e4d287b2

D       services/java/com/android/server/wm/StackBox.java
```

Note the "D" on the last line that tells us that the commit deletes the file in question (if you add the `--diff-filter=D` option you'll only get commits that deletes the file but then you might lose out on commits that rename the file). Feeding the commit id to `git tag --contains` tells you in which release this change was introduced:

```
$ git tag --contains ed6649f89f236ea9e665028bd33d6d804b906a92
android-5.0.0_r1
android-5.0.0_r2
android-5.0.0_r3
android-5.0.0_r4
android-5.0.0_r5
android-5.0.0_r5.1
android-5.0.0_r6
android-5.0.0_r7
android-5.0.1_r1
android-5.0.2_r1
android-wear-5.0.0_r1
```

I don't know this code well enough to be able to tell you what to use instead but I hope this commit contains what you need.

Comment: Thank you Magnus Bäck, it helped me. My work become much more difficult now :-(